# Play framework 2.0: Create validation error message using attribute value

Tags: scala, playframework, validation

Using scalaforms for the play framework, say that i have form such as:

```
case class User(name: String, emails: List[String])

val userForm = Form(
    mapping(
        "name" -> text,
        "emails" -> list(text).verifying("Emails are duplicated",x => SomeFunctionThatHandlesDuplicateEmails(x))
    )(User.apply, User.unapply)
  )
```

Where `SomeFunctionThatHandlesDuplicateEmails` is a function that returns false (thus, making the field invalid) if any of the emails received in the form is already in database.

Now then, my question is:

Is there a way to use the value of the validated field to create the error message? I would like to tell the user which emails in particular were duplicated, not just tell them "Emails are duplicated" as shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

verifying() takes a series of [Constraint[T]](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/scala/index.html#play.api.data.validation.Constraint).

You can see examples of Constraints implemented [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/validation/Validation.scala).

Note that the validation function in each receives the value to be validated e.g. "o"  in the "min" constraint repeated below:

```
 def min(minValue: Int): Constraint[Int] = Constraint[Int]("constraint.min", minValue) { o =>
   if (o >= minValue) Valid else Invalid(ValidationError("error.min", minValue))
 }
```

This could just as easily be:

```
 def min(minValue: Int): Constraint[Int] = Constraint[Int]("constraint.min", minValue) { o =>
   if (o >= minValue) Valid else Invalid(ValidationError("error.min", minValue, o))
 }
```

which would make "o" available to the error message formatter as {1} (minValue is {0}).

Comment: Thanks! That's certainly what i need.

Comment: what I want to use the standard constrain (nonEmptyText), but I want to change its error message, how would I do this?